# HQL Parameter not in Attribute

Tags: java, select, hql

I have two entities with a `ManyToMany` relation.

Role Core:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ROLE")
public class RoleCore extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "role_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "role_seq_gen", sequenceName = "ROLE_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "ROLE_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "NAME", length = 255)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "IS_ADMIN")
    private Short isAdmin;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_RIGHT", referencedColumnName = "RIGHT_ID"),
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FK_ROLE", referencedColumnName = "ROLE_ID"))
    private List<RightCore> rights;
}
```

Right Core:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "RIGHT")
public class RightCore extends BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "right_seq_gen")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "right_seq_gen", sequenceName = "RIGHT_SEQ", initialValue = 100, allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "RIGHT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "TOKEN", length = 255)
    private String token;

    @Column(name = "NAME_D", length = 255)
    private String nameD;

    @Column(name = "NAME_F", length = 255)
    private String nameF;

    @Column(name = "NAME_I", length = 255)
    private String nameI;

    @Column(name = "IS_ADMIN")
    private Short isAdmin;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "rights")
    private Collection<RoleCore> roles;
}
```

Now I want to get every RightCore that isn't set for one RoleCore. To do this I tried the two following statements and both throw a`java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException:"ORA-00936: missing expression"`

```
public interface RightCoreDAO extends JpaRepository<RightCore, Long> {

    @Query("select r from RightCore r where :role not in (r.roles)")
    List<RightCore> findByRoleNotInAndCategory(
            @Param("role") RoleCore role);

    @Query("select r from RightCore r where r not in (:rights)")
    List<RightCore> findByRightsNotInAndCategory(
            @Param("rights") List<RightCore> role);
}
```

EDIT:
How I call the methods:

```
    @Service   
    @Transactional  
    public class AuthorizationDataService {

    @Autowired
    RightCoreDAO rightCoreDao;

    public List<RightCore> loadAvailableRights1(RoleCore role) {
        return rightCoreDao.findByRoleNotInAndCategory(role);
    }

    public List<RightCore> loadAvailableRights2(RoleCore role) {
        return rightCoreDao.findByRightsNotInAndCategory(role.getRights());
    }
}
```

What exactly am I doing wrong and how can I make one of these statements work?

Sarajog

Comment: second query where clause comparison is not looking correct, need to compare at field level.

Comment: compare at field level? could you say me how to change it so that it should work?

Comment: like in first query: r.roles .

Comment: I can't do that because the given list is a parameter and the first query doesn't work so how should that help? I'll show you how I call the method in the second case and you should understand ;)

Comment: Your result can not be achieve by using attribute level.like this : @Query("select t from #{#entityName} t where t.attribute = ?1")
  List<T> findAllByAttribute(String attribute);[@Query](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.4.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html)

Comment: Moved to chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60981/discussion-between-sarajog-and-rudra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes the solution to a problem is really simpel. I only had to add elements before the list:

```
@Query("select r from RightCore r where :role not in elements(r.roles)")
List<RightCore> findByRoleNotInAndCategory(
        @Param("role") RoleCore role);
```

Answer (score 0):

idHope I understood your question correctly and I think you are looking for something like  :

To get all RightCores that isn't set for atleast single RoleCore (means find all rightcores whose roles is empty)
 for that you need to have a query like below:

```
select r from RightCore r where r.roles IS EMPTY;
```

**Edit:**

ok, after reading your comment you should have a query similar to:

```
select rc from rightcore rc where rc.id not in ( select ro.rights.id from rolecore ro where ro.id=:role_id )
```

**edit2:**

```
select ri from rights ri where ri.id not in( select rs.id from roles ro join ro.rights rs where ro.id=:role_id )
```

Comment: Sry, I think you misunderstood me, I need a list of all rights that can be added to a certain role. That they can be added they must not be added already to this role.
If I do it with java code it looks like this:

        List<RightCore> allRights = rightCoreDao.findAll();
        List<RightCore> rights = new ArrayList<>();
        for (RightCore right : allRights) {
            if (!role.getRights().contains(right)) {
                rights.add(right);
            }
        }
        return rights;

Comment: tried what you suggested:  org.hibernate.QueryException: illegal attempt to dereference collection [rolecore1_.role_id.rights] with element property reference [id]

Comment: Ok, just gave you an outline of query, look at my edit2. you got the error because of `ro.rights.id`

Comment: sry, couldn't make that statement work either but I need to get some rest now, thanks for your help